# System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format trying to download mc files

Tags: c#, wpf, string-formatting

I am trying to download `minecraft` files libraries and assets using listbox to select version then download by click on the button but when I click on the button I get this error

> "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'"

```
on await MCDownload(files, ctoken.Token);
```

please reply what should I do.
Thanks!

```
    private async void LaunchMinecraft1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(jsonloc + @"\versions\" + versionsList.SelectedItem.ToString()))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Version already exists");
            return;
        }
        ctoken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var files = await GetFiles(versionsList.SelectedItem.ToString(), totalPercentage.Content);
        await MCDownload(files, ctoken.Token);
    }
    public List<string[]> urls = new List<string[]>();
    public async Task MCDownload(List<string[]>urls, CancellationToken _ctsblock)
    {
        totalMB = 0;
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        sw.Start();
        int count = urls.Count;
        if (urls != null && urls.Count != 0)
        {
            System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            myTimer.Elapsed += (s, e) =>
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    downloadedMB.Content = string.Format("{0} MB", ((totalMB / 1024f) / 1024f).ToString("0.00"));

                }));
            };
            myTimer.Interval = 100; // 1000 ms is one second
            myTimer.Start();
            ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = Int32.Parse(Settings.Default["download_threads"].ToString());
            var block = new ActionBlock<string[]>(async url =>
            {
                try
                {
                    await DownloadLibraries(url);
                }
                catch (WebException) { }
                catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("There may have been some errors while downloading the game. It shouldn't be a problem though. If you experience any issue, try to reinstall again or contact us!");
                    }));
                    Console.WriteLine("ERRORE IN" + url[3] + "\r\n" + e);

                }
            }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Int32.Parse(Properties.Settings.Default["download_threads"].ToString()), CancellationToken = _ctsblock });

            foreach (var url in urls)
            {
                block.Post(url);
            }
            block.Complete();
            try
            {
                await block.Completion;
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                return;
            }

            myTimer.Stop();
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                downloadedMB.Content = null;
            }));
            progressBar.Value = 100;
            progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Most likely you're trying to convert a string to some other data type.  Post the code for `GetFiles`.

Comment: **StackTrace please !** I guess it's at `ToString("0.00")` - Try to use `Math.Round()` instead. You can pass an `int` to define the number of deciaml spaces you want !